# errors in importing json file in mongo db

Tags: json, mongodb

After typing `mongod` I got the log below:

```
2015-11-21T21:51:11.424-0800 I JOURNAL  [initandlisten] journal dir=/data/db/journal
2015-11-21T21:51:11.424-0800 I JOURNAL  [initandlisten] recover : no journal files present, no recovery needed
2015-11-21T21:51:11.438-0800 I JOURNAL  [durability] Durability thread started
2015-11-21T21:51:11.439-0800 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=22458 port=27017 dbpath=/data/db 64-bit host=(name)-MBP
2015-11-21T21:51:11.439-0800 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] 
2015-11-21T21:51:11.439-0800 I JOURNAL  [journal writer] Journal writer thread started
2015-11-21T21:51:11.439-0800 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: soft rlimits too low. Number of files is 256, should be at least 1000
2015-11-21T21:51:11.439-0800 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] db version v3.0.7
2015-11-21T21:51:11.439-0800 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] git version: nogitversion
2015-11-21T21:51:11.439-0800 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] build info: Darwin yosemitevm.local 14.5.0 Darwin Kernel Version 14.5.0: Wed Jul 29 02:26:53 PDT 2015; root:xnu-2782.40.9~1/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64 BOOST_LIB_VERSION=1_49
2015-11-21T21:51:11.439-0800 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] allocator: system
2015-11-21T21:51:11.439-0800 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] options: {}
2015-11-21T21:51:11.456-0800 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] waiting for connections on port 27017
```

It seems like I am having a warning and an error but is connected.

Now, I'm following MongoDB's document to test out how the database works.
In one of the tutorials, it tells me to import a json file into my mongo db.

I input the following:

```
mongoimport --db test --collection restaurants --drop --file primer-dataset.json
```

and the result is :

```
2015-11-21T21:57:36.533-0800    [........................] test.restaurants 0.0 B/11.3 MB (0.0%)
2015-11-21T21:57:37.066-0800    Failed: error connecting to db server: no reachable servers
2015-11-21T21:57:37.066-0800    imported 0 documents
```

Can anyone tell me how to fix this problem?

I did `brew update` to update everything. So my mongodb version is 3.0.7 (the latest one)
And I'm in development mode using homebrew.

Comment: have you started mongo server? with mongod?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the error message says:

> Failed: error connecting to db server: no reachable servers

The first step would be to **test, whether the MongoDB server can be reached** by hand. To do that, type

```
mongo
```

in a command line shell. If it does not work, the problem might be due to a firewall setting. (The MongoDB port, which is [27017 by default](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/default-mongodb-port/), might be blocked).

Also, you gave the `mongod` command and the output. To make sure that `mongod` is still running, you can type

```
ps aux | grep mongod
```

in the shell.

Comment: it's not a right answer but you gave me an idea to solve the problem. thanks!

Comment: @Kahsn if this is not the completely working solution then you should post your answer which can be useful to future users  and accept it. That is how things work around here.

Comment: @Kahsn: You are welcome. If you write an answer, it might help other people. (You can also write a short comment what was missing, or feel free to edit this post).

Comment: It was a stupid mistake on not running two terminals separately. I was using one terminal to do the operations. I dumped all connections first and connected to the database and opened new tab for a terminal to import the data. And it worked.